Amcl packages doesn't publish the tf transform between map and odom
Currently, i am working on localizing a robot using amcl package.The 3 inputs required for amcl package are provided as follows:
1- Map:provided by using gmapping package.
2- Laser scan: provided by RPlidar.
3- Odometry: provided by a node i implemented.
On running amcl and visualizing on Rviz, nothing seems to be operating.I debugged the issue as follows:
1-First, i suspected that the odometry_publisher is malfunctioned.However, i concluded that this was not the case as it works just fine on running gmapping.
2-Second, i checked the rqt graph and it looked okay.
3-Third, i ran the command roswtf and there were no warnings or errors
4-fourth, i ran the command (rosrun tf tf_echo map odom) and then i figured that the problem is that no tf update occurs between map and odom frames which is the responsibility of amcl node.
5-Fifth, i tried changing the transform_tolerance parameter in AmclConfig from 0.1 to (1,5,0.5) and nothing changed when i tried all these values.
Kindly advice how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

You have a conceptual misunderstanding: AMCL and gmapping are generally not executed at the same time.
You can create a map using gmapping. As clearly explained on the wiki page, the gmapping node will publish map->odom transform as it works.
After you have created and stored a map (for example in a .png file), you can then use map_server and AMCL to localize the robot on your map. If you want AMCL to publish the map->odom transform, you have to set the parameter tf_broadcast to the correct value.
